# RoR - why am I getting duplicate records saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, duplicates

I've got a many-to-many relationship set up with quizzes, quiz_questions, and quiz_questions_links. I had the form to create a quiz and add existing questions to it working great.  Now I need to let users add new questions manually.  But my form is now trying to insert two records into the quiz_questions_links table for each manual question that gets entered, and I can't figure out why.  Here is a sample posting from the form:

```
Parameters: {
  "commit"=>"Create", 
  "quiz"=>{
    "keyword_list"=>"", 
    "quiz_questions_links_attributes"=>{
       "1"=>{ "sequence"=>"1", "quiz_question_id"=>"2" }, 
       "2"=>{ "sequence"=>"2", "quiz_question_id"=>"9" }
    }, 
    "quiz_questions_attributes"=>{
      "1"=>{
        "answers_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
            "content"=>"Manual Question Answer 2"}}, 
        "correct_answer_attributes"=>{
          "content"=>"Manual Question Answer 1", 
          "correct_answer"=>"1"}, 
        "content"=>"Manual Question"}
    "opening_blurb"=>"test"
    etc...
```

So a quiz gets submitted with attributes for a quiz_question (which is the manually entered question) and attributes for quiz_questions_links (which are the existing questions being attached to this quiz).  Hopefully this makes sense.  The key parts of my quiz controller looks like this:

```
if @quiz.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Quiz was successfully created.'
  redirect_to([:cms, @quiz])
end
```

This properly creates any new quiz_questions, with their answers.  It then correctly inserts quiz_questions_links records for the existing questions added to the quiz and new manually created quiz_questions. But then it tries to insert duplicate records for the manually created quiz_questions. I can't figure out why it is inserting the duplicate records.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT: removed the questions loop in the controller as it wasn't needed, added the relevant portions of each model below.**

```
#quiz.rb
has_many :quiz_questions_links, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :quiz_questions, :through => :quiz_questions_links, :uniq => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_questions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_questions_links

#quiz_question.rb
has_many :quiz_questions_links
has_many :quizzes, :through => :quiz_questions_links

#quiz_questions_links.rb
belongs_to :quiz
belongs_to :quiz_question
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_questions in your quiz model?  You shouldn't have to loop through the quiz questions and save each one in the controller if so. Try that and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I am using that, so I removed the questions loop.  I get the same issue.  From the log, now it first inserts the quiz, then the quiz_questions_links for the existing questions. Then it inserts the quiz_question and answers, then tries to create a link for it twice.  I'll edit my question to reflect my code change and add the relevant parts of each model.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to get this question answered.  Instead I'll be using a pop-up form to add a new question.